# ASP.NET Session Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

1st Query......
I have a session variable cityId through which i find all the record. When i leave my application unattended  for  sometime then session expires & it does get the value for city & then throws exception.  How I can redirect to a error page when session expires like this.

2nd Query

When I click some page(myprofile.aspx), then i checks if the user is loged in or not, if user is not loged in then redirect to the login page & if loged in then show the page
If I give the user login if user not logined to view the myprofile.aspx then when the use logs in the it should directly go the myprofile.aspx page rather than whatever i provided after login.

Help Me Out.

Comment: You should probably split this into two separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

***Ans of the first question 
need to handle following event in global.asax file***

**Session_End**

The Session_End Event is fired whenever a single user Session ends or times out.

***Ans of the second question 
need to handle following event in global.asax file***

**Application_AuthenticateRequest**

The Application_AuthenticateRequest event indicates that a request is ready to be authenticated. If you are using Forms Authentication, this event can be used to check for the user's roles and rights.

Comment: @user373083 - go to msdn or serach about global.asax will give your whole idea

Comment: Session_End is raised only if the session is "inProc".

Answer (score 0):

> How I can redirect to a error page
>   when session expires like this.

I would only agree with this if your page displays sensitive information. Otherwise, say the user is viewing the page and upon becoming idle, you just made the information the user was looking at disappear.  Granted, you have a profile page in the case, but what if the user were viewing some sort of report that takes time to load? You would then force the user to rerun his/her report that he/she already had results for.

You can use the Session_End event in a Global.asax file as Pranay suggested.  With AJAX or plain JavaScript, you could notify the user that their session is about to time out / has timed out. Or adversely, you could wait until the session timeout exception is thrown once the user attempts a post back and turn custom errors on in your web.config.  If you still insist on redirecting the user on session timeout, use this in your Session_End event:

```
Response.Redirect("myRedirectPage.aspx",true);
```

You would want to specify `true` as the second parameter to end the response after redirection.

As for your second question, there are several ways to handle logins in ASP.NET. If you want to take care of the plumbing yourself,

- use the Application_BeginRequest
  event in your Global.asax file to
  check whether the user has logged in
  (i.e. whether `Session["cityId"]` is
  null)
- store your session information upon
  login and use `Response.Redirect` to
  forward your user to the profile
  page.

Otherwise, if you want to leverage built-in ASP.NET features, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx.

Then just use `Request.UrlReferrer` as Srinivas suggested.

Comment: `Session_End` isn't a request based event, therefore a `Response.Redirect` won't do anything in there.

Answer (score 0):

In my apps, I don't redirect when session expires, but I DO redirect to the login page on the NEXT operation that the user does. So in other words, they could sit and stare at a page for hours and even if the session expires nothing will happen - UNTIL they request a different page. At the beginning of every page_load, first thing I do is check that they are still 'logged in', and if not they get redirected:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["myUser"] != null)
            myUser = (User)Session["myUser"];
        else
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?Mode=Timeout");
```